# OR conflict between other conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT * FROM `Contacts` 
WHERE `Zona` = '1' 
AND `Responsable` = '9' 
AND `AllowComercialVisit` = 'Call_Again'
-- the problem are OR's --
OR `AllowComercialVisit` = 'Busy' 
OR `AllowComercialVisit` = 'Not_answered' 
-- the problem are OR's --
AND `DateRecall` <= '2016-06-20 13:04:52' 
AND `DateRecall` >= '2016-06-20 12:39:52' 
ORDER BY `DateRecall` ASC LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that the query should **ONLY** shows the rows between the first and the second 'DateRecall' , but return all the rows with 'Call_Again','Busy' and 'Not_answered' without filtering the date.

Any solution will be appreciated !

Comment: Never, ever, *ever* mix `OR` with `AND` without using parentheses to make your grouping explicit, in any language. Even if it's not strictly required in some situations, no one is going to be able to figure out your intentions without them.

Comment: While I don't agree that "no one is going to be able to figure out your intentions without them," I absolutely agree with always using parentheses. The only exception I make is when you are making exactly one comparison in languages that support it, like Python; in all other cases, parentheses not only make your code more readable, they protect you from order of operations issues (and other, harder to quantify issues, like certain boolean quirks in PHP that make no logical sense but are still averted this way). For SQL queries, also consider levels of indentation for nesting clarity.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A simple [`IN()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) would solve this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Contacts` 
WHERE `Zona` = '1' 
    AND `Responsable` = '9' 
    AND `AllowComercialVisit` IN ('Call_Again','Busy','Not_answered') 
    AND `DateRecall` BETWEEN '2016-06-20 12:39:52'
                         AND '2016-06-20 13:04:52' 
ORDER BY `DateRecall` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

In general, `AND` has precedence over `OR` , when using `OR` try using parentheses ->

```
WHERE COND1 AND COND2 AND (COND3 OR COND4) AND COND5
```

Which will force the optimizer to follow your precedence and not the default one.

Comment: Couldn't you also use BETWEEN to further shorten the query? I realize it doesn't make a difference to the optimizer, but I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Contacts` 
WHERE `Zona` = '1' 
AND `Responsable` = '9' 
AND (`AllowComercialVisit` = 'Call_Again' OR `AllowComercialVisit` = 'Busy' OR AllowComercialVisit` = 'Not_answered')
AND `DateRecall` <= '2016-06-20 13:04:52' 
AND `DateRecall` >= '2016-06-20 12:39:52' 
ORDER BY `DateRecall` ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Just surround the OR's with parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

Try to group the OR statements as they are related to same column,
i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM `Contacts` 
WHERE `Zona` = '1' 
AND `Responsable` = '9' 
AND (`AllowComercialVisit` = 'Call_Again' 
OR `AllowComercialVisit` = 'Busy' 
OR `AllowComercialVisit` = 'Not_answered' ) 
AND `DateRecall` <= '2016-06-20 13:04:52' 
AND `DateRecall` >= '2016-06-20 12:39:52' 
ORDER BY `DateRecall` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IN()` statement instead of `OR`s :

```
SELECT * FROM `Contacts` 
WHERE `Zona` = '1' 
    AND `Responsable` = '9' 
    AND `AllowComercialVisit` IN('Call_Again','Busy','Not_answered')
    AND `DateRecall` <= '2016-06-20 13:04:52' 
    AND `DateRecall` >= '2016-06-20 12:39:52' 
    ORDER BY `DateRecall` ASC LIMIT 1
```